# Rails .where query chained to sql function, is there a way to call it on the results without converting them to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a method that ranks user's response rates in our system called `ranked_users`

```
   def ranked_users
    User.joins(:responds).group(:id).select(
      "users.*, SUM(CASE WHEN answers.response != 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) avg, RANK () OVER ( 
        ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN answers.response != 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) DESC, CASE WHEN users.id = '#{
        current_user.id
      }' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
        ) rank"
    )
      .where('users.active = true')
      .where('answers.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.now - 12.months, Time.now)
  end
```

`result = ranked_users`

I then take the top three with `top_3 = ranked_users.limit(3)`

If the user is not in the top 3, I want to append them with their rank to the list:
`user_rank = result.find_by(id: current_user.id)`

Whenever I call `user_rank.rank` it returns 1.  I know this is because it's applying the find_by clause first and then ranking them.  Is there a way to enforce the find_by clause happens only on the result of the first query?  I tried doing `result.load.find_by(...)` but had the same issue.  I could convert the entire result into an array but I want the solution to be highly scalable.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect lots of users with lots of answers and high load on your rating system - you can create a materialized view for the ranking query with (user_id, avg, rank, etc.) and refresh it periodically instead of calculating rank every time (say, a few times per day or even less often). There's gem [scenic](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic) for this.

You can even have indexes on rank and user id on the view and your query will be two simple fast reads from it.